# Насколько безопасен алгоритм

Tags: криптография

Допустим я хочу зашифровать число 100. Выбираю случайное большое число (наш ключ), допустим
10^27+126737912 и умножаю на 100.

Передаю другому человеку, и он этим же ключом расшифровываем сообщение (делит результат и прошлого шага на ключ).

Насколько безопасно использовать такой метод шифрования, если ключ передаётся не по интернету, а лично, допустим на бумажке? :)

P.S Я думаю нереально, т.к если я умножу 10 на 15 (150) и передам другому человеку по открытому каналу, хакер никак не сможет восстановить 10 из 150 без ключа.

Comment: Одно число? да... но когда накопится массив данных, особенно соотносимый с активностью и обстоятельствами - тут я бы уже не поручился за 100% защищённость... да и терморектального криптоанализа никто не отменял.

Comment: я так понимаю это что-то типо упрощённого RCA. Причём сильно. За пару попыток можно подобрать ключ тупо через GCD

Comment: Совершенно бесполезный алгоритм, если вам нужно будет передать не одно число, а, например несколько миллионов чисел, как это бывает на практике.

Comment: вообще я бы советовал не изобретать алгоритмы. Там люди с опытом и знаниями иногда ошибаются.

Comment: А можете на практике показать как можно взломать этот алгоритм? Ну вот опять же, допустим мне нужно зашифровать 10, ключ 55, результат 550. Ключ неизвестен никому, кроме отправителя и получателя.

Comment: @Akina а скажите пожалуйста что такое терморектальный анализ ?

Comment: @Demon__ANT паяльник поудобнее засунуть и спросить)

Comment: Еще раз: проблемы начнутся, когда вам понадобится передать второе число, а потом и третье. Если каждый раз для этого придется встречаться и передавать код на бумажке - то уж передавайте на бумажке сразу ваше секретное сообщение, с просьбой эту бумажку впоследствии сьесть

Comment: А нельзя использовать один и тот же ключ?

Comment: Можно, но с каждым новым сообщением все проще и проще будет отследить закономерность. Почитайте например про [Turing Bombe](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombe).

Comment: Принцип этой машины основан на криптоанализе, т.к немцы каждый день передавали одно и то же сообщение в начале (точно не помню какое, вроде 'Доброе утро/день'), а если я собираюсь передать случайные числа? или информацию, которую приведу к такому виду, чтобы нельзя было провести анализ, или это бы заняла нерациональное время (вроде >5 лет)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот простой пример

Функция на python, шифрующая несколько сообщений

```py
def encrypt(data, key):
    return [key * x for x in data]
```

Функция расшифровывающая сообщения

```py
def decrypt(data, key):
    return [x // key for x in data]
```

С помощью нее зашифруем несколько чисел:

```py
key = 977240797922194023705
print('key      ', key)

plain = [7, 18, 113]
print('plain    ', plain)

encrypted = encrypt(plain, key)
print('encrypted', encrypted)

decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key)
print('decrypted', decrypted)
```

Вывод

```
key       977240797922194023705
plain     [7, 18, 113]
encrypted [6840685585455358165935, 17590334362599492426690, 110428210165207924678665]
decrypted [7, 18, 113]
```

А вот функция, с помощью которой хоть и неоднозначно, но с каждым новым сообщением все более точно можно получить ключ

```py
import functools
import math

def hackkey(data):
    return functools.reduce(math.gcd, data)
```

```py
hackedkey = hackkey(encrypted)
print('hacked   ', hackedkey)

print(hackedkey == key)
```

Вывод

```py
hacked    977240797922194023705
True
```

Comment: Могу я сделать что-то вроде этого?

import random
random.seed(key)

[item + random.randint(10000, 20000) for item in encrypted]

Comment: Тогда, если изначально ключа не было, то никак восстановить не получиться. Подбором это делать очень долго

Comment: @Bleno Экспериментируйте. код у вас есть. :)

Comment: Да проблема не в экспериментах, до этого примера а бы так и использовал этот метод шифрования, но, как видите, матика легко взломала его, а код написать не проблема

Comment: функция взламывающая ключ не "подсматривает" изначальный ключ или изначальный набор данных. она получает набор из нескольких зашифрованных сообщений и с неплохой вероятностью угадывает ключ. Так что рандомность не влияет ни на что.

Comment: Но тем не менее, код защитился от вашей функции взлома https://pastebin.com/RLEHkBvT

Comment: Теперь с точки зрения математики, числа никак не похожи друг на друга

Comment: Вы __для каждого сообщения__ выбрали новый ключ. Смысл ключа шифрования в том, чтобы он служил хотя бы для передачи нескольких сообщений. Если бы пришлось договариваться о ключе каждый раз, проще было бы передавать не __ключи__ при личной встрече, а __сами сообщения__. Надежнее только не передавать ничего вовсе. Нет передачи - нет возможности взлома.

Comment: Так с помощью random.seed эти уникальные ключи зависят от изначального ключа. Можете проверить, просто примените несколько раз функцию к одним и тем же данным, ключи и результат будет одинаковым.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97095/discussion-between-extrn-and-bleno).

Answer (score 8):

Нет, небезопасен. Даже для передачи 1 числа это опасно. Для числа в примере мы имеем всего

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому останется всего порядка сотни вариантов а что мы собственно передавали. Если мы передадим ещё одно число, например 9, то у нас останется всего 16 вариантов ключа. Такая защита не имеет смысла.

В общем советую почитать что-то о ассиметричном шифровании, например RSA.

Comment: Не математик, не совсем понял как проводились расчёты. Я просто не понимаю как можно восстановить множитель из произведения. Допустим в примере 10 и 15 там куча вариантов, т.к я мог умножить 1 на 150, 2 на 75, 3 на 50 и тд... А если ключ будет большой длины? Если я хочу зашифровать случайные 10 чисел, то их никак не восстановить, если с зашифрованным сообщением не передаётся хэш изначального, и то, если использовать какой-нибудь CRC16/32 то тогда вообще никак. Но это и не требуется. Вы так и не показали как на примере мне получить число 10 из 150.

Comment: @Bleno ну 10 на 15 это 150. Там всего 12 делителей. Даже если брать извращения вида ключ равен 1. Ну и это вы хотите сказать защита? И ещё, как только вы отправите 2 число, например 11, останется всего 4 варианта. Это вообще мало.

Comment: Так а что мне даёт информация о 12 делителях? Задача так и не решена, я как хакер получил зашифрованное сообщение 150 и знаю, что оно было зашифрованно этим методом, как мне получить исходное сообщение? Я думаю для анализа нужно больше данные, но если передавались случайные числа?

Comment: @Bleno, ну в случае одного числа, да, невозможно однозначно установить множитель. Но если вы можете безопасно передать ключ, то почему бы так же безопасно не передать само сообщение (1 число)?

Comment: @eanmos банальный шифровальный блокнот тут лучше даже будет. Чем такие произведения

Comment: @eanmos допустим 2 человека встретились и обменялись ключами, либо ключи передавались зашифрованными с помощью rsa, а в будущем можно обмениваться сообщениями без использования rsa, проводя только одну операцию умножения на символ.